# Updating next array in the array of objects with content from previous array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a state object which looks something like this:

```
this.state = {
  stages: [
      {name: 'Stage 0', tasks:['task 0', 'task 1', 'task 2', 'task 3'], stageId: 0},
      {name: 'Stage 1', tasks:['task 4', 'task 5', 'task 6'], stageId: 1},
      {name: 'Stage 2', tasks:['task 7', 'task 8'], stageId: 2},
      {name: 'Stage 3', tasks:['task 9'], stageId: 3}
],
```

I have to update the state such that once I click a button the task-name for e.g. 'task 3' moves to the tasks array of Stage 1. Updated State should look like this:

```
this.state = {
      stages: [
          {name: 'Stage 0', tasks:['task 0', 'task 1', 'task 2'], stageId: 0},
          {name: 'Stage 1', tasks:['task 4', 'task 5', 'task 6', 'task 3'], stageId: 1},
          {name: 'Stage 2', tasks:['task 7', 'task 8'], stageId: 2},
          {name: 'Stage 3', tasks:['task 9'], stageId: 3}
    ],
```

The button has an `onClick` event handler which takes task-name as input and it should move the task to the next Stage. I tried to splice the data and push it to the tasks array of next stage but the state update was not proper.

Any help would be great!

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, actually

Comment: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @HereticMonkey the naming of the question is quiet similar but the logic isn't

Comment: From the linked article: "If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**," (emphasis in the original). Also, be sure to read and understand the answer. Note that the highest-voted answer replaces the existing array with a new array. Considering your question lacks code for your attempt at solving the problem, the duplication should get you on your way toward the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript `indexOf` and `splice`:

```js
const state = {
  stages: [{
      name: 'Stage 0',
      tasks: ['task 0', 'task 1', 'task 2', 'task 3'],
      stageId: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Stage 1',
      tasks: ['task 4', 'task 5', 'task 6'],
      stageId: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Stage 2',
      tasks: ['task 7', 'task 8'],
      stageId: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'Stage 3',
      tasks: ['task 9'],
      stageId: 3
    }
  ],
};

const { stages } = state;
let task3Found = false;
const newStages = stages.map(stage => {
  const task3Index = stage.tasks.indexOf('task 3');
  if (task3Index > -1) {
    stage.tasks.splice(task3Index, 1);
    task3Found = true;
  } else if (task3Found) {
    stage.tasks.push('task 3');
    task3Found = false;
  }
  return stage;
});

const newState = { stages: newStages };

console.log(newState);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reducer` to build updated state. find item using `indexOf` and delete item using `splice`.

```js
const stages = [
  {
    name: "Stage 0",
    tasks: ["task 0", "task 1", "task 2", "task 3"],
    stageId: 0
  },
  { name: "Stage 1", tasks: ["task 4", "task 5", "task 6"], stageId: 1 },
  { name: "Stage 2", tasks: ["task 7", "task 8"], stageId: 2 },
  { name: "Stage 3", tasks: ["task 9"], stageId: 3 }
];

const updatedStages = (stages, item, new_stage) => {
  return stages.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const stage = { ...curr };
    const idx = stage.tasks.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
      stage.tasks.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    if (stage.name === new_stage) {
      stage.tasks.push(item);
    }
    acc.push(stage);
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

console.log(updatedStages(stages, "task 3", "Stage 1"));

// const { state: { stages } } = this.state;
// this.setState({ stages: updatedStages(stages, "task 3", "Stage 1") });
```

Comment: Isn't state immutable? I cannot push() directly right? Also, Shouldn't we use this.setState()

Comment: @user7098526, I missed to add on updating state. Just updated the answer with last commented lines. Basically get the current state.states, and update on a copy (using reduce).